# NullPointerException while setting prepared statement parameters

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

I think this is a bug.
I'm using latest MySQL JDBC library.
I have multiple threads. Each thread execute a query and for each row add a batch to a prepared statement.

Sometimes the instruction "stmt.setLong(i, aLong)" launch a NullPointerException.
stmt,i and aLong are not null.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = db.prepareStatement("myinsert");
while (rs.next()) {
    long aLong = rs.getLong(1);
    ...
    stmt.setLong(1,aLong);
    stmt.addBatch();
}
```

Here is the exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.java:3124)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3729)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setLong(PreparedStatement.java:3751)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setLong(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:127)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setLong(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:127)
>       at com.mypackage.MyClass$MyThread.run(MyClass.java:117)

If I launch only one thread, it works.

The exception also occurs without apache dbcp2 library.

I'm going crazy!

Comment: Is the `PreparedStatement` to which the threads add batches shared across multiple threads?

Comment: No. Each thread creates its own PreparedStatement. Each PreparedStatement is an insert on the same table, but they are different objects.

Comment: I assume that the same goes for the the result set `rs` in your example, right?

Comment: Yes. Each thread executes that piece of code.

Comment: This is very strange: the symptoms are really consistent with a situation when one thread invokes `setLong` concurrently with another thread invoking `addBatch` on the same `PrepareStatement` object. This is what I would check in the first place - i.e. that no `PreparedStatement` object is shared across multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem removing these lines of codes before creation of the ResultSet

```
Statement stmt = Database.getDatabase().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

From MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html).

> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row. After this, any result sets created with the statement will be retrieved row-by-row.

Comment: If you read on a little bit on the [linked documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) you will see _"There are some caveats with this approach. You **must read all of the rows** in the result set (or close it) **before you can issue any other queries** on the connection, or an exception will be thrown."_ However I would have expected a cleaner exception than a NPE.